# Data recovery solutions/methods

Tags: filesystems, data-recovery

I accidentally formatted my hard disk, but I was able to see all my files and recover them by using the **GetDataBack** recovery tool.

Is there a way to just restore the complete hard drive *in place*, relinking the deleted files and folders to the file system structure so everything appears as it was, without using another hard drive?

I mean, I want to just link all the files to the partition structure.

Simply revering the deleted files to the same partition in a single step?

Something like restoring partition table by **Testdisk**?

Comment: What operating system are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the issue is that, to relink deleted files, the tool needs to write directories.  And it won’t know *where* it can safely write until it has processed the entire file system and identified which sectors contain recoverable data and which ones are available.

Answer (score 1):

Without a prior made image of this drive this is not possible. The files have been marked as deleted and you will have to recover them onto another drive then move them back to where you want them. Do not recover the files to the hard drive you are recovering as this will possibly lead to data loss. Recover to another drive and then once you have verified you have the files you want, copy them back to the original drive.

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is to make an image of the mounted partition that you are trying to recover. True Image - Acronis is the most user friendly i can think about at this point. What this will do is that it will wrap your entire partition the way it exists and then you can restore using their software to any drive you want.

Hope this helps.

Comment: This does not answer what the OP asked.  They wanted to know whether you can **recover** an entire hard-drive if you accidently wiped it without a backup.

Comment: No that's not what the op asked at all. The question pertained to a method by which files that are available for recovery can be restored to the way they were, and not whether they can be recovered

Comment: It would not solve the, "I accidentally formatted my hard-disk" situation, however is an action you can take to have a similar effect yes.  I interpreted it is recover the entire disk after an accidental format (E.g. no backup).  Your solution is still valid however, just not quite what I think the OP was looking for.

Comment: any op you want i will use